# django allauth custom login with additional check apart from email and password

Tags: django, django-allauth

Here is my Custom login form from Allauth

```
class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(CustomLoginForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['login'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control' 

    def login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CustomLoginForm, self).login(*args, **kwargs)
```

The above works well when I use only Email and Password, and I would like to check another option, for example **custom_field** is **true**

I saw this reference, https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#login-allauth-account-forms-loginform and it says add your processing, but I struck with how to do it.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `Form`. You can **add any field** to it like you would for any other Django form. And you can override the `clean_my_field()` or `clean()` method to check the value of that field is correct and raise a `ValidationError` if it's not correct, like any other form.

The `login()` method is just to actually login the user, you only need to override it if you want to do something special when a user is logged in. This method is only called when the form is valid. So you don't need to override this method at all in your case.

If you're not actually adding a field to your form, but just need to add a check on the user when **authenticating** the user, then you should not do this in the form, but in the [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends). Override the allauth authentication backend to add a check when authenticating a user:

```
from allauth.account.auth_backends import AuthenticationBackend

class MyAuthenticationBackend(AuthenticationBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, **credentials):
        user = super().authenticate(request, **credentials)
        if user.custom_field == True:
            return user
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: You are right and I need a special think like `user.have_access == True`. I just strucked here to construct the `login()` method

Comment: How to check this `user.have_access == True` under login() method along with email and password

Comment: So have_access is not an extra field in your form? Why did you mention custom_field in your question then?

Comment: I guess that doesn't matter I might check it directly in login() method or I will pass through form..

Comment: You shouldn't do this kind of check in the `login()` method because it is called after the form validates. So there's no good way to return an error message to the user.

Comment: How should I make my application understand `MyAuthenticationBackend` as my `AuthenticationBackend`?

Comment: It's in the link I mention in my answer. Click on the link "authentication backend".